# Unable to push to heroku after removing submodule

Tags: git, heroku, git-submodules

I removed a submodule from my code, when I try to push to heroku now, I get:

```
remote: Git submodules detected, installing:
remote: No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'submodule/path'
remote:
remote: ! Push rejected, submodule install failed
remote:
```

I am using Heroku's buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git

With this `.buildpacks` file:

```
https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick-cedar-14
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

Is there something I can do to fix this? Do I just need to delete this app and start a new one (this is obviously very undesirable).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [heroku-repo](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo) plugin to reset the repo for the app:

```
$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo.git
$ heroku repo:reset -a APP
```

And then you can deploy again:

```
$ git push ....
```

Comment: If you're having trouble executing the first command, try "heroku plugins:install heroku-repo" instead.

Comment: Good Answer. Looks like the new way is `heroku builds:cache:purge -a APP` https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo#reset .

Comment: builds:cache:purge doesn't seem to exist now and repo:purge_cache didn't fix the submodule issue for me. reset does

Comment: `heroku-repo` doesn't work with latest version of `heroku version` `heroku/8.0.2 darwin-x64 node-v16.19.0`. See: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo/issues/124